# Movesense: Get precise timestamps when leads are connected?

Tags: movesense

I'm trying to get precise timestamps from the moment when the leads are connected/disconnected together on the Movesense sensor.

Subscribing to WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_STATES_STATEID() and checking the timestamp when on the onNotify section seems to only give values between 500ms intervals. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct (and only) way to do it. The detection in v2.0 and earlier is limited to the 500 ms accuracy.

The detection algorithm is improved in coming release 2.1 which will contain:

- instant notification on Leads-ON when not measuring HR/RR/ECG
- 500ms accuracy of Leads-OFF when not measuring HR/RR/ECG (limitation of current hardware)
- notification on Leads-ON and Leads-OFF when measuring HR/RR/ECG (fast on ECG measurement, slower on HR/RR)

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*